# module 'scipy.optimize' has no attribute 'anneal'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I tried to run following program of using python 3.5.1.

```
from scipy import optimize
optimize.anneal(f, input_vector0, lower = 0, upper = 2*np.pi)
```

I got the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy.optimize' has no attribute 'anneal'.
```

Can anybody tell me what should I do to fix this? i really appreciate it !

Comment: `anneal` was deprecated in scipy 0.14 (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.14.0.html#deprecated-features), and removed from 0.16 (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.16.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes).

Comment: Use `basinhopping` instead

Comment: If you *really* want simulated annealing rather than basin-hopping, you could use the standalone implementation in the [`simanneal` package](https://github.com/perrygeo/simanneal)

Comment: Thanks. I have simanneal installed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it is removed in 0.16 and higher.
Replace anneal with basinhopping.
refer to [link](https://github.com/msmbuilder/msmbuilder/issues/619)